# ESP-IDF on VSCODE libraries

Tags: visual-studio-code

So I started using ESP-IDF for a university project on vscode and I can't figure out how to add the two libraries that I need. Can someone explain me how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the libraries as component.
You can find some libraries in this link
https://components.espressif.com/

and if you dont find, you can search in this link
https://esp-idf-lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

For better clarity are you talking about ESP-IDF librarys or custom ones?

You can possibly add every library provided by Espressif or custom ones. I would recommend to stick to the Espressif guidline of organising your projects:

https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/build-system.html#example-project

I would be Happy to help if you provide further infos